# pasar un list de objetos que contienen otros objects a Json en Java

Tags: java, json, netbeans, arraylist, restful

Tengo un servicio web resftul echo en Java en Netbeans (NO MAVEN) con varias clases que entre ellas están relacionadas con llaves foráneas. Por ejemplo, tengo una clase Notes que tiene dos llaves foráneas (idUsuari y idIncidencia). Desde el Postman, hago un GET con el método que viene por defecto al generar el servicio, que devuelve un List y me lo muestra en formato Json porque así es como lo tengo puesto en el metodo get:

Método:

```
GET
    @Override
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Notes> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }
```

Y me devuelve:

```
[
  {
    "dataNota": "2017-04-01",
    "descripcio": "nota de la incidencia",
    "id": 1,
    "idIncidencia": { //objeto Incidencia
      "dataFi": "2017-04-06",
      "dataIncidencia": "2017-03-25",
      "dataInici": "2017-04-06",
      "descCurta": "Aixeta trencada",
      "descLlarga": "La aixeta del lavabo situat a la dreta està bessant aigua continuament",
      "id": 1,
      "idEstat": {
        "id": 2,
        "nomEstat": "assignada"
      },
      "idLocalitzacio": {//objeto Localitzacio
        "id": 12,
        "nomLloc": "dpt. exportació"
      },
      "idPrioritat": {//objeto Prioritat
        "id": 2,
        "nomPrioritat": "normal"
      },
      "idUsuariObertura": { //objeto Usuari
        "bloquejat": false,
        "cognoms": "Olivera Cortes",
        "contrasenya": "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
        "correu": "EulaliaOli@gmail.com",
        "id": 2,
        "idTipus": { //objeto TipusUsuari
          "id": 2,
          "nomTipus": "gestor"
        },
        "idUsuari": "EulaliaOli2",
        "mobil": "698899663",
        "nom": "Calatina"
      },
      "idUsuariOperari": { //objeto Usuari
        "bloquejat": false,
        "cognoms": "Olivera Cortes",
        "contrasenya": "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
        "correu": "EulaliaOli@gmail.com",
        "id": 3,
        "idTipus": { //objeto TipusUsuari
          "id": 2,
          "nomTipus": "gestor"
        },
        "idUsuari": "EulaliaOli",
        "mobil": "698899663",
        "nom": "Eulalia"
      }
    },
    "idUsuari": { //objeto Usuari
      "bloquejat": false,
      "cognoms": "Campmany",
      "contrasenya": "0c924da91233daf35ad47a7745d10edf",
      "correu": "turing.joan@gmail.com",
      "id": 7,
      "idTipus": { //objeto TipusUsuari
        "id": 2,
        "nomTipus": "gestor"
      },
      "idUsuari": "Joan",
      "mobil": "",
      "nom": "Joan"
    },
    "metodologia": "manual"
  },

...mas registros con la misma estructura...
```

Lo que quiero es convertir este listado de objetos (que contiene otros objetos y a la vez otros objetos) a un String en formato Json. He probado con Gson, JSONObject, Jackson y no me devuelve nada, de queda el Postman parado como pensando.

No se si el problema es que estas librerias no reconocen los distintos niveles dentro de la jerarquía de objetos o el EntityManager que hay detrás de éstos métodos restful.

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: El objeto que te devuelve el método tiene formato JSON. ¿Qué es lo que necesitas realmente?

Comment: Quieres meter ese JSON anidado dentro de un String? o quieres meter ese JSON anidado dentro de objetos? Podrías ser mas específico.

Comment: Quiero meter ese JSON anidado dentro de un String que siga la estructura de un json: [{"id":"1","dataNota":"2017-03-28","descripcio":"descripcio",....}]. La finalidad es que el metodo GET devuelva un Response con el codigo http, la descripcion (OK, Bad Request..) y el String en formato json.

Comment: No entiendo bien que quieres, quieres retornar un String o un json , tu ahi estas devolviendo un JSON por `@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})`  . Si quieres devolver un JSON con mas informacion como es el la respuesta , tiene que devolver otro DTO en realidad y no `List<Note>`

Comment: El objeto JSON que me devuelve el método lo quiero pasar a String.

Comment: Al final lograste hacer algo de esto?

Comment: Si. Recorri el listado de objetos y usé el método toString de la clase para montar un listado de Strings (estos Strings con la estructura de un json). Sé que parece un poco lioso, pero es la solución que encontré en ese momento.

Gracias por preguntar!